# How to determine Degrees of Freedom in Linear (Mixed Effect) Regression

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, lme4-nlme, degrees-of-freedom

In a statistics class we had a final homework to work with the data set `lexdec` of `languageR` (full script at the end). The task was to check if several effects influence subject's reading times (`RT`). We started with a simple model ("Is the RT affected by the number of trials?") and extended it ("Has NativeLanguage any impact", etc.), until we ended up with this:

```
model4 = lmer(RT ~ Trial + NativeLanguage + (1|Word) + (1 + Trial|Subject), lexdec)
```

This was correct (and since this is not an actual analysis but a toy example, we can for now ignore the warnings about the model not converging...). My team partner and I, however, wanted to know more: How to read and interpret the output to check if the effect we try to predict with the model is significant?

A method we learned is the t test. In the simplest model, which is without mixed effects, we get the results for free:

```
summary(lm(RT ~ Trial, lexdec))
```

yields the interpretable

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.4172041  0.0144549 443.948   <2e-16 ***
Trial       -0.0003060  0.0001256  -2.435    0.015 *
```

Sweet! In case we fixed our alpha value to the standard .05 (or .025, as it's a two-sided test), the Trial influence is actually significant.

But `lmer` does not provide this, instead we only get the t values reported. So here's our script to check if the values are significant:

```
ttest <- function (model, effect, df, alpha=0.05) {
    # Performs a two-sided t-test for a given alpha value on the given model.
    t <- abs(coef(summary(model))[effect, 't value'])
    q <- qt(1 - alpha / 2, df=df)
    paste('|t| =', round(t, 3), '>', round(q, 3), '?', t > q)
}
```

Now the tricky part: How to come up with the degrees of freedom (df)? I always understood df as the number of variables I can permutate independently (sometimes constraining others, e.g. robotic joints).

Very often I get thrown at with definitions like: $N-k-1$ (see e.g. here [Multiple linear regression degrees of freedom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55310/multiple-linear-regression-degrees-of-freedom)), or of course the df formulae for Student's and Welch's t tests. All of them result in different numbers of df, but against infinitely many they wouldn't matter much anyway (the [wikipedia t value table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Table_of_selected_values) nicely shows that even for 100+ it's almost unimportant for "our" small behavioral experiments).

Said that, it seems to be a plausible assumption that the authors of such libraries already solved that problem, and yes, in the `summary` (of the `lm`!) there's also a number of dfs: `F-statistic: 5.931 on 1 and 1657 DF,  p-value: 0.01498`. Wait, 1657? This seems like a lot. But it's the numbers of samples ($N=1659$) minus two, thus: $1659-k-1$ with $k=1$, which must be the only variable, `Trial`.

So I assume for the library the number of samples is the best guess. But: If I cleanly write my model before I would test my subjects, I would not know with how many df I would end up with (will I have 30 subjects? Or only 29 because one is ill?), as that number depends on $N$. So a variable must be something in my model, and of course I can find someone who agrees with me ([Degrees of Freedom Calculation in Linear Mixed Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144285/degrees-of-freedom-calculation-in-linear-mixed-model)):

> In the [...] model you have a parameter for the intercept, a variance parameter for each random effect term and a variance parameter for the observations given the random effects

If I count those I come up with seven: Intercept, Trial-Variance, NativeLanguage-Variance, Word-Intercept-Variance, Subject-Intercept-Variance, Subject-Trial-Variance, Residual.

This looks much cleaner, but unfortunately it changes a lot of our significant results, even for the simple model. While the built-in `lm` tells us: `Pr(>|t|) = 0.015`, we now find: `|t| = 2.435 > 4.303 ? FALSE`, because the df are too small now.

Additionally for the complex model we get multiple t values. Which ones should we consider? Is something significant iff all are significant? One? I heard a lot about corrections for multiple testing - is it already needed if I test multiple parameters?

Can someone shed some light into this significance and df darkness I fell into? Is my approach even correct this way? Or is there no simple answer and I always have to take into account many different things as df – and can just assume infinitely many by just using enough samples and participants (I sometimes hear that having too many is also not really good, without explanations, but I assume it's due to overfitting?)?

A similar question is [How should I determine degrees of freedom for t-test in ordinal regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231685/how-should-i-determine-degrees-of-freedom-for-t-test-in-ordinal-regression), which is unanswered, and I enjoyed [How to get the degree of freedom when doing multiple linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173775/how-to-get-the-degree-of-freedom-when-doing-multiple-linear-regression), which unfortunately compares nested models - something in which I am not interested at this time.

Here is a full working example code to see what I am talking about, followed by its output:

```
library('languageR')
library('lme4')

ttest <- function (model, effect, df, alpha=0.05) {
    # Performs a two-sided t-test for a given alpha value on the given model.
    t = abs(coef(summary(model))[effect, 't value'])
    q = qt(1 - alpha / 2, df=df)
    paste('|t| =', round(t, 3), '>', round(q, 3), '?', t > q)
}

model1 = lm(RT ~ Trial, lexdec)
summary(model1)
print(paste("Is reaction time affected by the number of trials only?", ttest(model1, 'Trial', 2)))

# snip models 2-3

model4 = lmer(RT ~ Trial + (1 + Trial|Subject) + (1|Word) + NativeLanguage, lexdec)
summary(model4)
print(paste("Is reaction time still affected by trials if considering native language and by-subject variance?", ttest(model4, 'Trial', 7)))
print(paste("Is reaction time still affected by native language if considering by-subject variance?", ttest(model4, 'NativeLanguageOther', 7)))
```

Output:

```
> library('languageR')
> library('lme4')
> 
> ttest <- function (model, effect, df, alpha=0.05) {
+   # Performs a two-sided t-test for a given alpha value on the given model.
+   t = abs(coef(summary(model))[effect, 't value'])
+   q = qt(1 - alpha / 2, df=df)
+   paste('|t| =', round(t, 3), '>', round(q, 3), '?', t > q)
+ }
> 
> model1 = lm(RT ~ Trial, lexdec)
> summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = RT ~ Trial, data = lexdec)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.53961 -0.16943 -0.04366  0.11594  1.18357 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.4172041  0.0144549 443.948   <2e-16 ***
Trial       -0.0003060  0.0001256  -2.435    0.015 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.2412 on 1657 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003567,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.002965 
F-statistic: 5.931 on 1 and 1657 DF,  p-value: 0.01498

> print(paste("Is reaction time affected by the number of trials only?", ttest(model1, 'Trial', 2)))
[1] "Is reaction time affected by the number of trials only? |t| = 2.435 > 4.303 ? FALSE"
> 
> # snip models 2-3
> 
> model4 = lmer(RT ~ Trial + (1 + Trial|Subject) + (1|Word) +NativeLanguage, lexdec)
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00759802 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
> summary(model4)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: RT ~ Trial + (1 + Trial | Subject) + (1 | Word) + NativeLanguage
   Data: lexdec

REML criterion at convergence: -922.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3256 -0.6159 -0.0954  0.4647  6.0361 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr 
 Word     (Intercept) 5.942e-03 0.0770873      
 Subject  (Intercept) 3.179e-02 0.1783087      
          Trial       4.937e-07 0.0007026 -0.72
 Residual             2.869e-02 0.1693814      
Number of obs: 1659, groups:  Word, 79; Subject, 21

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)          6.3403360  0.0477379  132.82
Trial               -0.0002435  0.0001778   -1.37
NativeLanguageOther  0.1640987  0.0563356    2.91

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Trial 
Trial       -0.609       
NtvLnggOthr -0.506  0.001
convergence code: 0
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00759802 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?

> print(paste("Is reaction time still affected by trials if considering native language and by-subject variance?", ttest(model4, 'Trial', 7)))
[1] "Is reaction time still affected by trials if considering native language and by-subject variance? |t| = 1.369 > 2.365 ? FALSE"
> print(paste("Is reaction time still affected by native language if considering by-subject variance?", ttest(model4, 'NativeLanguageOther', 7)))
[1] "Is reaction time still affected by native language if considering by-subject variance? |t| = 2.913 > 2.365 ? TRUE"
```

Comment: Thanks, I indeed did not take the tour (I just did) since I am already an active member of the stackoverflow community. Can you maybe point out what is different from that [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), or what (stats.SE) guidelines I missed? I apologize that my question is long, but I don't know how to make it shorter. Maybe you can take some time and read through it to point me to an answer or tell me what I need to clarify, so that someone can? That would be very helpful.

Comment: The main takeaway, being already familiar with the general format of the SE communities, is what is on-topic here and what is expected of a good question.  You could probably pair down your question a bit to focus more on the problem of generating an ANOVA table for a linear mixed effects model.  I have had the same question myself, but it was more a point of curiosity than a need for the data, so I moved on without finding an answer.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to an ANOVA table directly. Can you explain it a bit more? I found that you just check the df per variable for it. Of course, I might get the df which are close to the number `lm` provides then, but that won't help me much as I found other answers (referenced in the question) which state that my only df are the variables of my model, i.e. the intercepts and variances. I want to understand when and why I would need to calculate the df for my t test in which way. I am sorry to hear that you gave up on your quest, but thanks for giving me the chance to elaborate mine.

Answer (score 9):

There is an extensive discussion of this topic under the heading [Why doesn’t `lme4` display denominator degrees of freedom/p values? What other options do I have?](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#why-doesnt-lme4-display-denominator-degrees-of-freedomp-values-what-other-options-do-i-have) on the GLMM FAQ GitHub page.

Particularly, because of the [crossed random grouping factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/136579) (`Word` and `Subject`) in your linear mixed model, the following applies:

> When the data are not classical (crossed, unbalanced, R-side effects),
>   we might still guess that the deviances etc. are approximately
>   F-distributed but that we don’t know the real degrees of freedom –
>   this is what the Satterthwaite, Kenward-Roger, Fai-Cornelius, etc.
>   approximations are supposed to do.

We can use the package `lmerTest` to compute the Satterthwaite and Kenward-Roger approximations for the degrees of freedom:

```
library("lmerTest")

model4 <- lmer(RT ~ Trial + (1 + Trial | Subject) + (1 | Word) + NativeLanguage, lexdec)

summary(model4, ddf = "Satterthwaite")
# [...]
# Fixed effects:
#                       Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)          6.3403355  0.0477400 26.0766153 132.810  < 2e-16 ***
# Trial               -0.0002435  0.0001778 19.7606718  -1.369  0.18627    
# NativeLanguageOther  0.1640999  0.0563369 19.0229754   2.913  0.00892 ** 
# [...]

summary(model4, ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
# [...]
# Fixed effects:
#                       Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)          6.3403355  0.0483794 25.7103491 131.054   <2e-16 ***
# Trial               -0.0002435  0.0001778 19.8844304  -1.369   0.1862    
# NativeLanguageOther  0.1640999  0.0592290 19.0094714   2.771   0.0122 * 
# [...]
```

Comment: For those interested, the DOI of the paper on Kenward-Roger and Satterthwaite approximations is https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-016-0809-y